# Cypress - Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element - only in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, cypress, end-to-end

I have a grouping of Cypress tests that are failing, *only in my Jenkins environment*.  An entire `describe` block is failing to find an element.  Every test in the block starts with the same commands:

```js
describe("This section of tests", () => {
  it("Test for something in this section", () => {
    cy.login(); // custom login command, works in all other test blocks
    setupPage(); // page setup function, no problems in all other test blocks
    cy.wait(10000); // desperation wait

    cy.get("#toggle-detail-pane-button").click(); // issue here!
    // all tests in block run more assertions and commands after this
  });

  // more similar tests in block
});

// more describe blocks that also use cy.login and setupPage, with no issue
```

When I run these tests in the cypress test UI, they all pass.  When I run them in the terminal on my machine with `npx cypress run`, they pass.  When I ssh into a remote OpenStack terminal which is set up to run my project and run cypress, and run `npx cypress run`, they pass.

When I run the tests in Jenkins, which uses a handful of identical OpenStack instances to run cypress in parallel, the tests fail, consistently, with the following message:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `#toggle-detail-pane-button`, but never found it.

      at Context.eval (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/stuff/mytests.spec.js:519:8)
```

I have tried reorganizing my tests, rewriting them, etc, but no luck.  I cannot figure out what is going wrong here.  My Jenkins environment uses a custom [sorry-cypress](https://github.com/sorry-cypress/sorry-cypress) setup, and for some reason, the dashboard is not registering the tests, so I can't go and view any screenshots or videos (that is a whole separate can-of-worms problem).

Why would only these tests fail only in my CI/CD env?  How can I even begin to debug this?

#### Edit: screenshots

I was able to rerun the CI/CD with screenshots and videos, and then I was able to `scp` the files off of the instance with the failing tests.  When running on my machine, cypress has no problem finding the element:

[image]

When using the cypress selector playground on my machine, it finds it as well:

[image]

But in the screenshot I pulled off of the openstack instance running exactly the same test, it can't find it:

[image]

<sub>(Sorry for all the green, this is a proprietary app)</sub>

What gives?

Comment: Not that it helps you but I like your `// desparation wait` comment. I used such in the past as well. And I like both Jenkins and Cypress. Can you reproduce it with an MCVE and post it in a JS/HTML snippet here? Can you disable the parallel test runs on Jenkins temporarily or did you try that too already?

Comment: Ouch! https://docs.sorry-cypress.dev/ci/jenkins → ⚠ Under construction

Comment: Yeah there's no documentation there, so I basically [wrote my own](https://medium.com/geekculture/parallelizing-cypress-with-jenkins-aws-and-sorry-cypress-8241331fe50f).  As far as a MCVE, I'm really not sure how to do that considering it involves a complex and proprietary react codebase, with cypress, jenkins, and cloud computer resources.  I can try running the testing over jenkins not in parallel, but ultimately I need a solution that works in parallel.  I'll try that as soon as I can and report back.

Comment: I think I may also invest the time in getting sorry-cypress to work properly so that images and videos are properly uploaded to the sorry-cypress dashboard.  If I can manage that, I may be able to see what the heck is going on in those tests that's causing failures.

Comment: Hats off! Very good article! Are you aware of that you could simplify your stage steps, which are all the same there, with a single line calling a [Shared Library](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/15/declarative-notifications/#moving-notifications-to-shared-library)?

Comment: Yeah I've heavily refined my actual code since having written that article, I guess I should update it, but yes, agreed, no need to write the same 4 lines of code 4 times over

Comment: BTW, since you seem to be a JS front-end guy. Perhaps you have an answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704174/1744774). I usually work more on Java back-end and DevOps.

Answer (score 7):

Please update the default command timeout in cypress.config.js file using below line:

`defaultCommandTimeout: 10000`

Instead of 10000 you can use any value of time in miliseconds. Using this your, timeout issue will be resolved.

Comment: below is my overall code in cypress.config.js:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                        
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  defaultCommandTimeout: 8000,
  pageLoadTimeout:10000,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/examples/*.js',    
  }
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

That means there's an issue with your cy.visit() command. The page is not being loaded before the test that's why

Comment: The page is being loaded.  The screenshots above clearly show that (though perhaps the green NDA coverup makes that unclear)...but that is definitely not the answer.  Upgradinf to cypress ^8 seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

i resolve Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'Name' within the element...
cy.wait(6000);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

For us, none of the above worked unfortunately. Remix/vite was optimizing our dependencies, causing a page reload like here [Vite + Cypress : how to prevent reloading (due to optimized dependencies) causing the test to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469067/vite-cypress-how-to-prevent-reloading-due-to-optimized-dependencies-causin) and the only thing that solved it was "retrying" immediately after the initial reload had thrown the test.

```
describe(
  'ensure xyz works',
  {
    retries: {
      runMode: 2,
      openMode: 1
    }
  },
  () => {
    it('Should ...', () => {
      cy.visit('/...')

      cy.contains('Continue').click()

      // previously would consistently get stuck here

      cy.url().should('include', '/next-page')
   
      ...
    
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by getting the element by a selector or class instead of its id.

I went from:

```
cy.get('#mat-options-text').click()
```

to

```
cy.get('mat-options').click()
```