# Vite + Cypress : how to prevent reloading (due to optimized dependencies) causing the test to fail?

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vuetify.js, vite

When I'm running Cypress component test, sometimes i'm facing this :

```
17:34:59 [vite] ✨ new dependencies optimized: vuetify/components, vuetify/lib/components/VAppBar/index.mjs, vuetify/lib/components/VDivider/index.mjs, vuetify/lib/components/VToolbar/index.mjs, @vueuse/core
17:34:59 [vite] ✨ optimized dependencies changed. reloading

1) An uncaught error was detected outside of a test
```

And the test fails... If I relaunch tests a second time, everything is ok : all tests pass.
Anything I can do to prevent this ?

My `cypress.config.ts` is quite simple :

```
export default defineConfig({
  video: false,
  env: {
    codeCoverage: {
      exclude: ['cypress/**/*.*', 'src/**/*.cy.ts'],
    },
  },
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'vue',
      bundler: 'vite',
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      registerCodeCoverageTasks(on, config)

      return config
    },
  },
})
```

So do my `vite.config.ts` :

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(), // SFC
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
    istanbul({
      cypress: true,
      requireEnv: false,
    }),
  ],
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.mjs', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
  },
 }
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced a similar problem where my Cypress tests were failing on Firefox only with "TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module".

Looking at your `vite.config.ts` I see you're using `vite-plugin-vuetify`.

From the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#customizing-the-behavior):

> A typical use case for `optimizeDeps.include` or `optimizeDeps.exclude` is when you have an import that is not directly discoverable in the source code. For example, maybe the import is created as a result of a plugin transform. This means Vite won't be able to discover the import on the initial scan - it can only discover it after the file is requested by the browser and transformed. This will cause the server to immediately re-bundle after server start.
>
> Both `include` and `exclude` can be used to deal with this. If the dependency is large (with many internal modules) or is CommonJS, then you should include it; If the dependency is small and is already valid ESM, you can exclude it and let the browser load it directly.

So the solution is

```js
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  ...,
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['vuetify'],
    // or include: ['vuetify'], ?
  },
```

It sounds like it would make more sense to include rather than exclude as Vuetify is probably considered large, but I found that only exclude works for me.

You may also need to do the same for `@vueuse/core`.

---

P.S. You might also want to look at including `.vue` files in `optimizeDeps.entries` so Vite knows it needs to crawl them to find dependencies, if you are using single file components. Something like

```js
  optimizeDeps: {
    entries: ['./src/**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
```

Comment: `exclude: ['vuetify']` was the only thing that worked with `vuetify({ styles: 'none' })` as a plugin.

Comment: excluding the dependencies in this config, automatically fail my test. It seems Cypress couldn't import this module when we exclude in the config.

 > module is not defined at <unknown> (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/src/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.js?v=700361ce:1:14)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the library that was causing the dependencies to be optimized was `antd`.

I tried several different `optimizeDeps` options for Vite but none of them worked for me.

What I did instead was to find all imports of `antd` and change them to import from `antd/es` instead.

In your case I suspect that changing your `vuetify` imports to use `dist` instead of `lib` subfolder will fix the issue.

So instead of:

```
import { whatever } from 'vuetify/**lib**/whatever'
```

You could try:

```
import { whatever } from 'vuetify/**dist**/whatever'
```

Answer (score 0):

For us, none of the above worked unfortunately. Remix/vite was optimizing our dependencies as you describe, but the only thing that solved it was "retrying" immediately after the initial reload had thrown the test.

```
describe(
  'ensure xyz works',
  {
    retries: {
      runMode: 2,
      openMode: 1
    }
  },
  () => {
    it('Should ...', () => {
      cy.visit('/...')

      cy.contains('Continue').click()

      // previously would consistently get stuck here

      cy.url().should('include', '/next-page')
   
      ...
    
    })
  }
)
```